# OS X Yosemite - Vagrant: Failed to install / update plugins (ruby invalid option -H)

Tags: ruby, plugins, rubygems, vagrant, osx-yosemite

I've done a fresh install of OS X Yosemite and Vagrant on my Mac some days ago. The problem is, that every time when I try to update all plugins or install a vagrant plugin (vagrant-cachier), I'll get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

If I install a gem over the system's binary it works. So it seems to be a problem with the built-in vagrant binaries. I've also already installed the command line tools. My Vagrant Version is 1.7.2

I've already googled the problem for hours, but I didn't find this problem.

Did I forget anything or does anybody has a workaround for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I found the problem.
The problem was the path were Vagrant is installed. My SSD partition on OS X is called "Macintosh SSD" with a space in it. 
I renamed it to "MacintoshSSD" and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue *appears* to be that the 'embedded' binary of ruby is not happy with some older code in the JSON gem. Or something... I literally know nothing about ruby other than that it is a programming language and I installed it to use compass. And now here it is again with Vagrant.

ANYWAY I moved the embedded ruby to the side, and copied OS X's built-in ruby into the vagrant embedded binaries folder.

Something like:

```
sudo mv /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.2.0.0.p598
sudo cp /usr/bin/ruby /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.2.0.0.p481
sudo ln -s /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.2.0.0.p481 /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby
sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-fusion
Installing the 'vagrant-vmware-fusion' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vmware-fusion (3.2.1)'!
```

Yay.

Comment: Maybe nevermind.... it does build the plugin. But now it won't up my boxes, giving long spewing messages about broken gems and such. I tried reverting the ruby change ... putting Vagrant's original p598 version back in place, and then it gives an error about, guess what... the JSON gem.

Answer (score 0):

### Straight from HashiCorp... here is the troubleshooting checklist:

Hey there,

I am really sorry you are having problems installing that Vagrant plugin. We are aware of these issues, but we have not been able to narrow it down to a specific cause because it only affects a small subset of machines and we have not identified a common denominator yet.

First, please do not try and install the plugin using sudo. This can tamper with the permissions of other Vagrant plugins and cause Vagrant to error.

Second, please ensure you have the XCode Command Line Tools installed. You can install them by running:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and following the on-screen prompt.

After completing those steps, many users have found success by doing the following:

1. Completely uninstall Vagrant
2. Removing the /opt/vagrant and /Applications/vagrant directories.
3. Remove Vagrant's storage directory (~/.vagrant.d). **Warning:** If you
   have installed other Vagrant plugins or Vagrant plugin licenses,
   they will be removed!
4. Reinstall Vagrant from the official Vagrant installers:
   https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
5. Install the plugin

Additionally, please ensure the following:

- If there is a special character anywhere in Vagrant's path, you must
  choose a different directory. This includes spaces (like in a
  username or folder name) and parenthesis (like C:/Program Files
  (x86)). Unfortunately there is a bug in the language in which Vagrant
  is written that prohibits compiling native extensions under these
  circumstances.
- If you are using a Mac, please make sure you have accepted the XCode
  license agreement. In some situations, native extensions will fail to
  compile because XCode is prohibiting the installation due to an
  unaccepted license agreement. To accept the license agreement, simply
  open XCode - you will be prompted if you need to accept the
  agreement.

If the problem persists after taking these steps, please provide the output of the plugin installation's [debug](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html) logs.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Best,
Seth

Comment: I found that the second to last 'bullet' was my issue... my home folder on my Mac had a space in the path to it. So I set my VAGRANT_HOME environment variable to point to a location on my system that did not have spaces in the path. I set reasonable permissions. And did the whole re-install. Worked perfectly after that.